# Proof: if sequence of r.v.'s $(X_n)_n$ converges in prob. to $X$, there exists subsequence $(n_k)$ s.t. $(X_{n_k})_{n_k}$ converges completely to $X$

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables, proof-explanation, solution-verification

I quote **Gut(2005)**.

Recalling that starting from a sequence of random variables $\left(X_n\right)_{n\ge1}$ defined on a probability space $\left(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mathbb{P}\right)$, one says that such a sequence *converges completely* (c.c.) to the random variable $X$ iff:
\begin{equation}\label{eqtn:complete convergence of random variable}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}\left\{|X_n-X|>\eta\right\}<\infty\hspace{1.5cm}\text{for }\eta>0
\end{equation}
$$\text{(Alternatively, one says }X_n\overset{\text{c.c.}}{\longrightarrow}X\text{)}$$let us focus on the following theorem and on relative proof.

**Theorem.** Let $X_1,X_2,\ldots$ be random variables such that $X_n\underset{n\to\infty}{\overset{p}{\longrightarrow}}X$ *(that is, convergence in probability)*. Then there exists a nondecreasing subsequence $\left\{n_k, k\ge1\right\}$ of the positive integers such that
$$X_{n_k}\underset{n\to\infty}{\overset{c.c.}{\longrightarrow}}X$$

> **Proof.** By assumption, there exists a nondecreasing subsequence $\left\{n_k, k\ge1\right\}$ such that $$\mathbb{P}\left\{|X_{n_k}-X|>\dfrac{1}{2^k}\right\}<\dfrac{1}{2^k}\tag{1}$$
> Consequently:
> $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}\left\{|X_{n_k}-X|>\dfrac{1}{2^k}\right\}<\infty\tag{2}$$

---

My questions concern inequalities $(1)$ and $(2)$ along the proof:

1. I guess that it is stated that "by assumption, there exists [...]" since if a sequence converges then all subsequences converge to the same limit (in this case, in probability to $X$). However, I know that the $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ definition of convergence in probability consists in:
   $$\text{for any }\varepsilon>0, \delta>0\text{, there exists }N=N(\delta) \text{ s.t. }\mathbb{P}\left\{|X_n-X|>\varepsilon\right\}<\delta$$ for all $n\ge N$.
   However, in inequality $(1)$ I do not see exactly the same approach. It is not stated that the result holds at limit, that is for certain $N\ge n$, just to give an example. So, I am misinterpreting role of equation $(1)$? What is it exactly meant for?
2. In place of $(2)$ I would expect:
   $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}\left\{|X_{n_k}-X|>\dfrac{1}{2^k}\right\}<\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{2^k}\underbrace{=}_{\text{conv. geometric series}}1\tag{2.bis}$$
   So, why is $(2)$ that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The author is applying the definition of convergence in probability multiple times.

- With $\epsilon = 1/2$, there exists $n_1$ such that $P(|X_{n_1} - X| > 1/2) < 1/2$ (because $P(|X_n - X|>1/2) \overset{n \to \infty}{\longrightarrow} 0$).
- With $\epsilon = 1/2^2$, there exists $n_2 > n_1$ such that $P(|X_{n_2} - X| > 1/2^2) < 1/2^2$.
- With $\epsilon = 1/2^3$, there exists $n_3 > n_2$ such that $P(|X_{n_3} - X| > 1/2^3) < 1/2^3$.
- etc.

2. Your argument is fine, the series can be bounded by $1$, so it is therefore finite. The author did not feel it was necessary to write the intermediate steps.

Comment: As to point 1., do you mean that.."since one knows that $$P(|X_n - X|>1/2) \overset{n \to \infty}{\longrightarrow} 0\tag{1}$$then, for every subsequence $\left\{n_k\right\}$ it must hold that $$P(|X_{n_k} - X|>1/2) \overset{n_k \to \infty}{\longrightarrow} 0\tag{2}$$ Taking a certain $\left\{n_k\right\}$, with $k=1,\ldots$, by $(2)$ one can states that for each $k$:
$$\mathbb{P}\left\{|X_{n_k}-X|>\dfrac{1}{2^k}\right\}<\dfrac{1}{2^k}\tag{3}$$"
Is this what you mean?

Comment: @Strictly_increasing No this is not what I meant. Using (1) I'm just picking a single index $n_1$ (not a subsequence) so that the probability is $<1/2$. In the next step, I change the value of $\epsilon$ from $1/2$ to $1/2^2$ and choose another index $n_2$. In the next step, I select $n_3$, and build up the subsequence this way.

Comment: Oh, maybe I'm getting it now. You are "building up" a subsequence and not starting from a certain subsequence. However, the theoretical reference point for your reasoning is still that "since one knows that
$$P(|X_n - X|>1/2) \overset{n \to \infty}{\longrightarrow} 0\tag{1}$$
then, for every subsequence $\left\{n_k\right\}$ it must hold that $$P(|X_{n_k} - X|>1/2) \overset{n \to \infty}{\longrightarrow} 0\tag{2}$$", isn't it?

Comment: @Strictly_increasing Although (2) is a consequence of (1), I do not need to use it. I'm just using the very weak fact that if the sequence of probabilities converges to zero, then one of them is smaller than $1/2$.

Comment: Pardon, why"if the sequence of probabilities converges to zero, then one of them is smaller than $\dfrac{1}{2}$"? Why does that necessarily follow?

Comment: @Strictly_increasing If $a_1,a_2,\ldots$ is a sequence of nonnegative numbers that converges to zero, doesn't the definition of convergence imply that $a_n < 1/2$ for all sufficiently large $n$? (And thus there exists some $n$ for which $a_n < 1/2$)

Comment: All right, just considering $\varepsilon=1/2$ here [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_sequence#Formal_definition]. In my case and in your example in the main answer, one is considering $\delta=\epsilon=\frac{1}{2}$, isn't he?

Comment: @Strictly_increasing Yes